# What is a good approach/tool to embed a mini-language in Java app?

Tags: java, interpreter, dsl, evaluation

I am trying to solve the following problem:

- I have a Java app (not written by me) whose purpose is to take 2 report files (just comma separated table output), and compare each row and each column of the files to each other cell by cell - basically, for regression testing.
- I would like to enhance it with the following functionality:

  - Let's say I made a software change that causes all the values in column C1 to increase by 100%.
  - When comparing specific column "C1", the software currently will report that 100% of values in C1 changed.
  - What I want to do is **to be able to configure the regression tester to NOT simply compare "is C1 in row1 the same in both files", but instead apply a pre-configured comparison rule/formula to the field, e.g. "Make sure that C1 value in file#2 is 2 times bigger than C1 value in file #1"**. This way, not only will I suppress 100% of bogus regression errors that say every row's column C1 doesn't match, but ALSO catch any real errors where column C1 is not exactly 100% bigger using new software.

When coding this sort of functionality in Perl previously, the solution was very simple - simply **code custom per-column comparator configuration into a Perl hash stored in the config file**, with the hash keys being columns and hash values being Perl subroutines for comparing 2 values any complicated way I wanted.

Obviously, this approach will NOT work with Java since I can NOT write custom comparator logic in Java and have the Java differ evaluate/compile/execute those comparators during differ runtime.

This means that I need to come up with some domain specific interpretable language that my differ would interpret/evaluate/execute.

Since I'm not very familiar with Java ecosystem and libraries, I'm asking SO:

**What would be a good solution for implementing this DSL for configurable comparator logic?**

My requirements are:

- The solution must be "free as in beer"
- The solution must be "shrink wrapped". E.g. an existing library, that I can simply drop into my code, add the config file, and have it work.

  Something which requires me to write my own BNF grammar and provides generic grammar parser for which I must write my own interpreter is NOT acceptable.
- The solution must be reasonably flexible as far as data crunching and syntactically rich. E.g.:

  - you should be able to at the very least pass in - and reference/address from within the DSL - an entire row of data as a hash
  - it should have reasonably complete syntax; at the very least do basic string operations (concatenate, substring, ideally some level of regex matching and substitutions); basic arithmetic including ability to do `abs(val1 - val2) > tolerance` on floating point #s; and basic flow control/logic such as conditionals and ideally loops.
- The solution should be reasonably fast, and must be scalable. E.g. comparing 100x100 size files should not take 10 minutes with 10-20 custom columns.

If it matters, the target environment is Java 1.6

Comment: Try one of the embeddable scripting languages, like SISC or Jython.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple dynamic JVM programming languages that can be easily integrated in Java applications without much effort. I think it would be worth looking into [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy) and/or [Scala](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala).

Another possible option would be creating your own DSL using [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) or [XTend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/).

Comment: 1. Can xText support my requirement of being able to pass in a HashMap or something similar and access individual values? Have conditionals or loop control structures?

Comment: 2. Could you please elaborate on integrating Groovy/Scala into Java? I know they are Java based, but are there standard tools for running Groovy/Scala subroutines from within your Java code and passing them data structures as parameters?

Comment: Have you checked the links i added for Groovy and Scala? They should show you possible ways of calling Groovy/Scala function from Java and how to pass parameters between them. Iam not exactly sure with XText. I think it should be possible, however it might be a bit oversized for your target.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever it comes to dynamic features in Java I come up with Janino, a charming runtime and in-memory compiler. In your case it would give you something similar to an eval(...) for plain Java, see: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Basic#Basic-expressionevaluator

The point here is that you don't have a DSL for your test configuration but you can use plain Java syntax to write custom expressions in your test configuration.

The only requirement that won't be fulfilled by the solution proposed below is that you can address a whole row from within the config file. The solution assumes that you write a Java test class that iterates through your test-data value-by-value (or better pair-by-pair) and uses your configured expressions to compare single values. So the dynamic part are the expressions, the static part is the iteration of your test-data.

However the code needed is very small and simple as shown below:

Config File (Java properties syntax, key is column name, value is test expression):

```
# custom expression for column C1
C1  = a == 2 * b           
# custom expression for column C4
C4  = a == b ^ 2           
# custom expression for column C47
C47 = Math.abs(a - b) < 1
```

Sketch for test code:

```
// read config file into Properties
Properties expressions = Properties.load(....);

// Compile expressions, this could also be done lazily
HashMap<String, ExpressionEvaluator> evals = new HashMap<String, ExpressionEvaluator>();
for (String column : expressions.stringPropertyNames()) {
    String expression = expressions.getProperty(column);
    ExpressionEvaluator eval = new ExpressionEvaluator(
        expression,                  // expression
        boolean.class,               // expressionType
        new String[] { "a", "b" },   // parameterNames
        new Class[] { int.class, int.class } // parameterTypes, depends on your data
    );
    evals.put(column, eval);
}

// Now for every value pair (a, b) check if a custom expression is defined 
// for the according column and if yes execute: 
Boolean correct = (Boolean) theEvalForTheColumn.evaluate(
    new Object[] { a, b }          // parameterValues
);
if (!correct) throw Exception("Wrong values...");
```

As said on the Janino pages, performance for compiled expressions is pretty good (they are real java byte code), only the compilation will slow down the process. So it might be a problem if you have many custom  expressions but it should scale well with an increasing number of values. hth.

Comment: I'm not yet sure if it will be useful for this task without prototyping, but a great information in any case! +1

Comment: What do you mean by "prototyping"?

Comment: build a mini differ that can call Janino

Comment: Ah Ok. FYI: It took me about 10 minutes to set up a running example.

Answer (score 0):

No imbedded language is needed. Define your comparator as an interface.

You can load classes which define the interface at runtime using class.forName(name),
where name can be specified by command line arguments or any other convenient means.

your comparator class would look something like

```
class SpecialColumn3 implements ColumnCompare
{ boolean compare(String a,String b) {...}
}
```